# SQL Server Graph Edge Insert

Tags: sql-server, graph, sql-graph

In my model, I have two nodes ACCOUNT and WARNING. ACCOUNT can have zero to many WARNING.

the ACCOUNT node has multiple columns with the ACCOUNTNUMBER as the unique columnn.

the WARNING node has WARNINGCODE, WARNINGDESCRIPTION, and EXPIRATIONDATE.
I also create an edge table HAS_A_WARNING, which besides the usual columns, I have ExpirtionDate.

I have a staging table that has the ACCOUNTNUMBER, WARNINGCODE, WARNINGCODEDESCRIPTION,EXPIRATIONDATE.
when I run the following statement, I get an error:

*Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 17    Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with  EXISTS.    Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.*

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[HAS_A_WARNING] 
values
(

 (SELECT
   ac.$node_id,
   w.$node_id,
   acw.ExpirationDate

 FROM dbo.Account ac
 join Stage.AccountWarning acw
 on acw.AccountNumber = ac.ACCOUNTNUMBER
 join dbo.Warning w
 on w.WarningCode = acw.WarinngCode)

)
```

Comment: Just remove the outside set of parentheses. Maybe a good time to review the syntax documentation for [insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). The VALUES version inserts a single row - your select statement obviously returns a resultset of multiple rows. And lastly - stop the laziness. ALWAYS specify the column list for the insert statement.

Comment: I had the column names before, didn't work either.

Comment: I tried this and it worked:


with edgeCTE as 
(SELECT
 ac.$node_id from_id,
 w.$node_id to_id,
 acw.ExpirationDate

 FROM dbo.Account ac
 join Stage.AccountWarning acw
 on acw.AccountNumber = ac.ACCOUNTNUMBER
 join dbo.Warning w
 on w.WarningCode = acw.WarinngCode
 ) 
 insert into [dbo].[HAS_A_WARNING]
 select * from edgeCTE

Comment: "didn't work either" is not useful information. And specifying the column list is a best practice. What you just did is a more complicated version of my suggestion - but at least it works for now.